# how to access a field from a variable?

Tags: apex

```
List<String> exchangeCurrencySplit = new List<String>({USD, EUR, CAD});

         String exchangeRateValues = '';
         List<Schema.SObjectType> objects = new List<Schema.SObjectType>{Exchange_Rate__c.SObjectType};
         for(Schema.SObjectType objType: objects){            
    for(Schema.SObjectFieldfld:objType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().values()){
             for(Integer i= 0 ; i < exchangeCurrencySplit.size(); i++){
                    if(exchangeCurrencySplit[i] == fld.getDescribe().getLabel()){

                          Exchange_Rate__c exch = new Exchange_Rate__c(); 
                          exch.(fld.getDescribe().getName()) = 1.2;
                    }                        
             }

         }
```

have error: Expression cannot be assigned  in exch.(fld.getDescribe().getName()) = 1.2;

Comment: What are you aiming to do here? (Please [edit]). `exch.(fld.getDescribe().getName())` is not an lvalue, something that can be assigned to.

Comment: I want to refer to a property object  exch.USD__c = 1.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the `.` dereference operator with a dynamic field name:

```
exch.(fld.getDescribe().getName()) = 1.2;
```

Instead, you have to use the [sObject method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) `put()`, which accepts a dynamic field name:

```
exch.put(fld.getDescribe().getName(), 1.2);
```

Edit: thanks to IllusiveBrian for reminding me that `put()` takes an `SobjectField` directly, simplifying this to

```
exch.put(fld, 1.2);
```

Comment: `put` and `get` have overloads for `Schema.SObjectField`, so no need to call `getDescribe().getName()` (unfortunately the overload's variable name is still called "fieldName", so it's easy to confuse it for the string overload).